# Horizontal plotting window in scrollwindow

Tags: python, matplotlib, pygtk

I am using Matplotlib with PyGTK on Windows XP.
I am planning to have a horizontally long plot window which I want to use for plotting real-time  data.

I have added `matplotlib.canvas` to scrollwindow. It's showing a horizontal scrollbar, but the plotting area only has the default size.

Any idea how to do this?

**Code:**

```
class plot(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.tw=tool.getToolWindow()
        self.create_win()
        self.tplot=None

    def create_win(self):

        sw=gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        sw.set_policy(gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC, gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC)
        self.tw.ewidget.pack_start(sw) #,True,True,0)
        self.fig = Figure(figsize=(15,6), facecolor='w')
        matplotlib.figure.SubplotParams(left=0.01, bottom=0.01, right=1.0, top=1.00, wspace=0.2, hspace=0.2)

        self.ax1 = self.fig.add_subplot(111)

        self.ax1.set_autoscale_on(True)


        self.ax1.axis('off')
        canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)

        sw.add_with_viewport(canvas)
        toolbar=NavigationToolbar(canvas,self.tw.ewidget)
        self.tw.ewidget.pack_start(toolbar,False,False,0)
        sw.show()
        canvas.show()
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you have tried?  What does it do? What did you expect it to do?  What do you _want_ it to do?